# What are the differences in Dokapon Kingdom Connected vs the PS2/Wii version?

Tags: version-differences, dokapon-kingdom

What are the differences between Dokapon Kingdom Connected (2023) on the Switch vs the original Dokapon Kingdom (2008) on the PS2 and Wii? Are there any new features?